# Create a env file containing default values in c++

Tags: c++

I'm creating a `c++` project that contains some specific configurations. Those configs can be calibrated depending the scenario.

As the problem that I trying to solve is a optimization problem and configurations like  `BigM` and `cycles` are values that makes difference depending the instance I believe that a configuration file will be a good choice.

As an example, I actually put in the beginning of my main file, like follow:

```
#define NUM_STABILIZED 1e6
#define bigM 1e6
```

Like `.env` that is used in `node` or `php` projects. There is a default pattern like `.env` file in `c++`?

In a better scenario, I believe that a "like" `.env` file as follow will be helpful to run massive tests with different approaches:

```
bigM 1e6
NUM_STABILIZED 1E6
```

Just to make easy to run tests without need to every time to recompile the code with different values in those (actual) constants.

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to pass arguments to `main` via `argc` and `argv`.  Do you know how to do that?  Is that not adequate for your needs?   If you're using Boost, their Program Options library is a good convenient way to do that.  It also supports setting options from files.

Comment: Note: `#define`s do not even at exist during compilation, since they all have been replaced by preprocessor, before even compilation began. So, they, definitely, don't exist during runtime.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, yes about `argc`and `argv`. As I have a lot of parameters on the test I faced that I can do a different approach using `argc` and `argv` that could be done creating a simple bash script that calls my program reading a file with different parameters and passing as parameters on my program will solve it.

Comment: And, thinking better, the `.env` approach will not work as I need to change the .env every time that I will use a different calibration.

Comment: See [boost::program_options](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/program_options.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to solve this problem is to pass the values as command line parameters:

```
./myapp --NUM_STABILIZED 1000000 --bigM 1000000
```

This approach requires you to parse the command line. You can use a library for this, for example [cxxopts](https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts). Default values could be used if there are no command line parameters.

You could also pass the values via environment variables. Read them using [getenv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv).

If you want support for .env files in your project, you could implement an own parser or use a library, for example [cpp-dotenv](https://github.com/adeharo9/cpp-dotenv).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing, but there are plenty of options, some of the common ones that i am used to are..

1. Pass the variables as program arguments.
2. Read the needed variables from environment..You can actually create a wrapper script which can set the environment variables and invoke the program.
3. Pass the config file which contains all needed arguments as program option.
4. Read the config file from an predefined environment variable.

The usual approach is to have a combination of these, for example, you read all the default values from a config file (using above option 3 or 4) and for every key you override these values if they are supplied using (option 1 or 2)

The [Property_tree from boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/property_tree/tutorial.html) and [Program options from boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/program_options.html) provides a cross-platform support to your needs.

Comment: The combination is a good approach. A bood approach is using cxxopts from @schteppe answer and your combination that check and overrides if does not exists. Thanks.